# How to use ActionBar, ViewPager and Fragments and correctly replace fragments inside pages

Tags: android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am still new to Android developing and iam trying to develop an app with actionBar tabs, swipe effect and fragments. But for the last 3days i don´t solve a problem with replacing fragments inside the viewPager. I have tried so many ideas found on several internet pages but nothing help me to solve this problem. No my code is wasted because of so much replacing, out commenting and so on that i have deleted it and start a new on.
But i guess for this time i need to understand the behavior of the fragment(State)PagerAdapter completly bevor i implement it again.
So i have for now a few questions.
1. is it possible to use actionbar and viewPager and additionally to use fragments which i can replace on a page with another one?
2. is it possible to save the state of those replacements and switch to an other pager interact there with replacing same fragment pages and then come back to the previous page an restore the page?
3. what do i need to achieve such behavior? Which methodes do i really need to override? How do i need to override them?
4. is it possible to use for all pages instances of the same fragment? Do i need something to distinguish them? So can i use for this fragments, instantiated from the same class, also the same xml layout file? Do the viewPager know which resource on which layout ion which page iam currently want to replace?
5. Why are there only tutorials which just explain actionbar, or just explain swipe with ViewPagerAdapter, but rather explaining how fragment replacing within viewpager and actionbar can be achieve additionally. Simply combining such tutorials?

So i excuse my bad mood writing but iam still be hacked off of this damn problem. And please excuse my bad english iam not a native speaker iam just using my old english knowledge from school.
I would be so overly happy if any one could help me maybe give me an example for it.

please help, Justus

Edit on 30/03/2014
Here are my sources iam currently using.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private Menue[] menuesDto;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String jsonString = extras.getString("jsonString");
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Menue[]>() {
    }.getType();
    this.menuesDto = g.fromJson(jsonString, type);

    createTabBar();
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Log.d("MyZooApp2", "onTabSelected at position " + tab.getPosition() +
    // " name " + tab.getTag());
    tab.setIcon(this.menuesDto[tab.getPosition()].getSelectedIcon());
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), true);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Log.d("MyZooApp2", "onTabUnselected at position " + tab.getPosition()
    // + " name " + tab.getText());
    tab.setIcon(this.menuesDto[tab.getPosition()].getUnselectedIcon());
}

private void createTabBar() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuesDto.length; i++) {
        Menue menue = menuesDto[i];
        FragmentBuilder.setTabIconForChangeState(menue);
        String name = menue.getName();
        ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText(name);
        tab.setIcon(menue.getUnselectedIcon());
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // Log.d("MyZooApp2", "onPageSelected at position " + arg0);
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
        }
    });
}

public MyViewPagerAdapter getMyViewPagerAdapter() {
    return myViewPagerAdapter;
}
}
```

MenueFragment.java:

```
public class MenueFragment extends Fragment implements ZooFragment, ResourceCaller {
private Menue menue;
private ListView listView;
private String[] navList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menue_fragment, container, false);
    init();
    if (menue.getNavs().size() > 0) {
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        new FileResourceLoader(menue, getActivity(), this).execute();
    } else {
        // createContentComponents();
    }
    return v;
}

public static MenueFragment newInstance() {
    MenueFragment f = new MenueFragment();
    return f;
}

@Override
public void init() {
    String jsonString = getArguments().getString("childNodes");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    this.menue = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Menue.class);
    navList = new String[menue.getNavs().size()];
}

private void createNavigationComponents(List<Nav> navs) {
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, navList));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            FragmentTransaction trans = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.nav_here, new EmptyFragment());
            trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            trans.addToBackStack(null);
            trans.commit();
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getMyViewPagerAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
}
```

MyViewPAgerAdapter.java:

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public static final int FRAGMENT1 = 0;
public static final int FRAGMENT2 = 1;
public static final int FRAGMENT3 = 2;
public static final int FRAGMENT4 = 3;
public static final int FRAGMENT5 = 4;

private final MainActivity mainActivity;
private ZooFragment[] fragments;

public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MainActivity mainActivity) {
    super(fm);
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    fragments = new ZooFragment[mainActivity.getTabCount()];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Menue menue = mainActivity.getMenuesDtoAtPos(position);
    switch (position) {
    case FRAGMENT1:
        if (fragments[FRAGMENT1] == null) {
            fragments[FRAGMENT1] = FragmentBuilder.getMenueFragment(mainActivity, menue);
        }
        break;
    case FRAGMENT2:
        if (fragments[FRAGMENT2] == null) {
            fragments[FRAGMENT2] = FragmentBuilder.getMenueFragment(mainActivity, menue);

        }
        break;
    case FRAGMENT3:
        if (fragments[FRAGMENT3] == null) {
            fragments[FRAGMENT3] = FragmentBuilder.getMenueFragment(mainActivity, menue);

        }
        break;
    case FRAGMENT4:
        if (fragments[FRAGMENT4] == null) {
            fragments[FRAGMENT4] = FragmentBuilder.getMenueFragment(mainActivity, menue);

        }
        break;
    case FRAGMENT5:
        if (fragments[FRAGMENT5] == null) {
            fragments[FRAGMENT5] = FragmentBuilder.getMenueFragment(mainActivity, menue);

        }
        break;
    }

    Log.d("MyZooApp2", "getItem: for Position: " + position + " added: " + menue.getName());

    return (Fragment) fragments[position];

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.length;
}
}
```

And the both layouts.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/nav_here"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#DDEE22"
    android:divider="#55FFAA"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#AA33EE"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope there will be someone who has another solution for my problem discribed in the comment of TisSarah.

Edit 31/03/2014:
If have changed my Listener implementations for Tab and viewpager listener like you recommended and added some LogCat Outputs.

```
VIA SWIPE:
03-31 19:10:05.914: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabUnselected at position 0 name Home
03-31 19:10:05.914: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabSelected at position 1 name null
03-31 19:10:05.924: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onPageSelected at position 1
03-31 19:10:06.895: D/MyZooApp2(5674): getItem: for Position: 2 added: Tiere
03-31 19:10:08.396: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabUnselected at position 1 name Zookarte
03-31 19:10:08.406: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabSelected at position 2 name null
03-31 19:10:08.406: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onPageSelected at position 2
03-31 19:10:09.187: D/MyZooApp2(5674): getItem: for Position: 3 added: Fütterung

VIA TAB SELECTION:
03-31 19:11:06.353: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabUnselected at position 2 name Tiere
03-31 19:11:06.353: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabSelected at position 0 name null
03-31 19:11:06.353: D/MyZooApp2(5674): getItem: for Position: 0 added: Home
03-31 19:11:06.984: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabReselected at position 0 name Home
03-31 19:11:06.984: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onPageSelected at position 0
03-31 19:11:11.488: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabUnselected at position 0 name Home
03-31 19:11:11.488: D/MyZooApp2(5674): onTabSelected at position 2 name null
03-31 19:11:11.498: D/MyZooApp2(5674): getItem: for Position: 2 added: Tiere
03-31 19:11:11.498: D/MyZooApp2(5674): getItem: for Position: 3 added: Fütterung

SWIPE + TAB SELECTION AND LISTITEM CLICKS:
03-31 19:18:27.123: D/MyZooApp2(9138): ListItem 0 on page Home clicked //After load item clicked -> Fragment replacement correct
03-31 19:18:38.094: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 0 name Home
03-31 19:18:38.094: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 2 name null
03-31 19:18:38.134: D/MyZooApp2(9138): getItem: for Position: 2 added: Tiere //swiping to page 2 and click -> Fragment replacement incorrect. It´s replaced on page 1
03-31 19:18:38.154: D/MyZooApp2(9138): getItem: for Position: 3 added: Fütterung    //same page (2) and click -> Fragment replacement incorrect. It´s replaced on page 1
03-31 19:18:38.344: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabReselected at position 2 name Tiere
03-31 19:18:38.344: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 2
03-31 19:18:39.615: D/MyZooApp2(9138): ListItem 0 on page Tiere clicked  //swiping to page 0 and click -> Fragment replacement incorrect.It´s replaced on page 1
03-31 19:18:41.107: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 2 name Tiere
03-31 19:18:41.107: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 1 name null
03-31 19:18:41.117: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 1
03-31 19:20:05.089: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 1 name Zookarte
03-31 19:20:05.089: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 2 name null
03-31 19:20:05.089: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 2
03-31 19:20:06.550: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 2 name Tiere
03-31 19:20:06.550: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 3 name null
03-31 19:20:06.560: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 3
03-31 19:20:07.020: D/MyZooApp2(9138): getItem: for Position: 4 added: Mehr
03-31 19:20:07.911: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 3 name Fütterung
03-31 19:20:07.911: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 4 name null
03-31 19:20:07.921: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 4
03-31 19:20:09.763: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 4 name Mehr
03-31 19:20:09.763: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 2 name null
03-31 19:20:09.853: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabReselected at position 2 name Tiere
03-31 19:20:09.853: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 2
03-31 19:20:11.074: D/MyZooApp2(9138): ListItem 0 on page Tiere clicked //a few swipes and tab selections done and back on page 0 and click -> Fragment replacement incorrect. It´s replaced on page 1
03-31 19:20:12.426: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 2 name Tiere
03-31 19:20:12.436: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 1 name null
03-31 19:20:12.436: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 1
03-31 19:20:13.397: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabUnselected at position 1 name Zookarte
03-31 19:20:13.407: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onTabSelected at position 0 name null
03-31 19:20:13.407: D/MyZooApp2(9138): onPageSelected at position 0
03-31 19:20:14.878: D/MyZooApp2(9138): ListItem 0 on page Home clicked //only tab         selections back on page 0 and click -> Fragment replacement incorrect. It´s             replaced on page 1

Fragment setup:
page 0 -> Fragment1 (Home) layout: frag1.xml contains programmatically added listitems from a json response
page 1 -> Fragment1 (Zookarte) layout: frag1.xml contains only an imageview
page 2 -> Fragment1 (Tiere) layout: frag1.xml contains programmatically added listitems from a json response
page 3 -> Fragment1 (Fütterung) layout: frag1.xml contains only an imageview
page 4 -> Fragment1 (Mehr) layout: frag1.xml contains only an imageview
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think this link might be very helpful to you: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

1. Yes.
   https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter
2. Yes. You'll save the fragment state as usual with savedInstanceSTate
3. Check out the above links, to hook it up to an actionbar tabbar
   you'll need to create a TabListener
4. Yes, just have your FragmentPagerAdapter create instances of the same fragment, which
   will inflate the same layout if you are inflating in your
   onCreateView method. The view pager will handle keeping track of
   which instance is on which page (well you will, in the viewpager).
5. You'll want to keep a list of Fragments in your view pager so that
   you can return the appropriate ones in the getItem method (I
   generally use a switch statement and some constants to keep track of
   which fragments to return for which view pager position).

It's a little frustrating but you'll get the hang of it!

Here's an Example

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public static final int FRAGMENT1 = 0;
    public static final int FRAGMENT2 = 1;

    private Fragment[] fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Activity activity, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
       fragments = new Fragment[2];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i){
            case FRAGMENT1:
                if(fragment[FRAGMENT1] == null) {
                     fragment[FRAGMENT1] = new FragmentOne.createInstance();
                }
                break;
            case FRAGMENT2:
                if(fragment[FRAGMENT2] == null) {
                     fragment[FRAGMENT2] = new FragmentTWO.createInstance();
                }
                break;
        }
        return fragments[i];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.length;
    }
}
```

You'll want to override the listeners in your activity class:

```
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mPagerChangeListener
        = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(0);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(position));
    }
};

private ActionBar.TabListener mTabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Sarah for your help, but unfortunately it doesnt solve my problems. I have tried a similar implementation for getItem(). The swiping and tab selection seem to perform correctly. But the fragment replacing on a tab/page doesnt act correct. Sometimes the fragment of the current -1 or current +1 is replaced. I dont know why. Is it absolutly necessary to override getItemPosition() in my PagerAdapter? And if so, how should i override it? Maybe it could be helpful if i post my code for the whole class?

Comment: I have extended your solution. Now i extend from FragmentStatePagerAdapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() after ft.replace(). But i dont change anything. :-(

Comment: I have added my sources.

Comment: I added some listeners that you want to implement with at least what's shown.

Comment: I added the output of your listener implementations.